# airflow - creating dag and task dynamically create the pipeline for one object

Tags: python, airflow

In airflow I want to export some tables from pg to BQ.

```
task1: get the max id from BQ
task2: export the data from PG (id>maxid)
task3: GCS to BQ stage
task4: BQ stage to BQ main
```

But there is a slight challenge, The schedule interval is different. So I created a JSON file to tell the sync interval. So if it is 2mins then it'll use the DAG `upsert_2mins` else 10mins interval (`upsert_10mins`) . I used this syntax to generate it dynamically.

JSON config file:

```json
{
    "tbl1": ["update_timestamp", "2mins", "stg"],
    "tbl2": ["update_timestamp", "2mins", "stg"]
}
```

Code:

```
import json
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.contrib.hooks.bigquery_hook import BigQueryHook
from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator import BigQueryOperator
from customoperator.custom_PostgresToGCSOperator import  custom_PostgresToGCSOperator
from airflow.contrib.operators.gcs_to_bq import custom_PostgresToGoogleCloudStorageOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator


table_list = ['tbl1','tbl2']

#DAG details
docs = """test"""
# Add args and Dag
default_args = {
    'owner': 'DBteam',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': days_ago(1),
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1)
    }

 

with open('/home/airflow/gcs/dags/upsert_dag/config.json','r') as conf:
    config = json.loads(conf.read())

def get_max_ts(dag,tablename,**kwargs):
    code for find the max record
    return records[0][0]

def pgexport(dag,tablename, **kwargs):
    code for exporting the data PGtoGCS
    export_tables.execute(None)


def stg_bqimport(dag,tablename, **kwargs):
    code to import GCS to BQ
    bqload.execute(None)

def prd_merge(dag,tablename, **kwargs):
    code to merge bq to main bq table
    bqmerge.execute(context=kwargs)

for table_name in table_list:
    
    sync_interval = config[table_name][1]
    cron_time = ''
    if sync_interval == '2mins':
        cron_time = '*/20 * * * *'
    else:
        cron_time = '*/10 * * * *'
    
    dag = DAG(
    'upsert_every_{}'.format(sync_interval),
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Incremental load - Every 10mins',
    schedule_interval=cron_time,
    catchup=False,
    max_active_runs=1,
    doc_md = docs
    )
    
    max_ts = PythonOperator(
        task_id="get_maxts_{}".format(table_name),
        python_callable=get_max_ts,
        op_kwargs={'tablename':table_name, 'dag': dag},
        provide_context=True,
        dag=dag
    )
   
    export_gcs = PythonOperator(
    task_id='export_gcs_{}'.format(table_name),
    python_callable=pgexport,
    op_kwargs={'tablename':table_name, 'dag': dag},
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag
    )

    stg_load = PythonOperator(
    task_id='stg_load_{}'.format(table_name),
    python_callable=stg_bqimport,
    op_kwargs={'tablename':table_name, 'dag': dag},
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag
    )    
    merge = PythonOperator(
    task_id='merge_{}'.format(table_name),
    python_callable=prd_merge,
    op_kwargs={'tablename':table_name, 'dag': dag},
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag
    )
    
    globals()[sync_interval] = dag
    max_ts >> export_gcs >> stg_load >> merge
```

It actually created the dag but the issue is from the web UI im able to see the task for the last table.But it has to show the tasks for 2 tables.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is creating 2 dags, one for each table, but overwriting the first one with the second.

My suggestion is to change the format of the JSON file to:

```
{
    "2mins": [
                "tbl1": ["update_timestamp", "stg"],
                "tbl2": ["update_timestamp", "stg"]
             ],
    "10mins": [
                "tbl3": ["update_timestamp", "stg"],
                "tbl4": ["update_timestamp", "stg"]
             ]
}
```

And have your code iterate over the schedules and create the needed tasks for each table (you will need two loops):

```
# looping on the schedules to create two dags
for schedule, tables in config.items():

cron_time = '*/10 * * * *'

if schedule== '2mins':
    cron_time = '*/20 * * * *'

dag_id = 'upsert_every_{}'.format(schedule)

dag = DAG(
    dag_id ,
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Incremental load - Every 10mins',
    schedule_interval=cron_time,
    catchup=False,
    max_active_runs=1,
    doc_md = docs
)

# Looping over the tables to create the tasks for 
# each table in the current schedule
for table_name, table_config in tables.items():
    max_ts = PythonOperator(
        task_id="get_maxts_{}".format(table_name),
        python_callable=get_max_ts,
        op_kwargs={'tablename':table_name, 'dag': dag},
        provide_context=True,
        dag=dag
    )

    export_gcs = PythonOperator(
        task_id='export_gcs_{}'.format(table_name),
        python_callable=pgexport,
        op_kwargs={'tablename':table_name, 'dag': dag},
        provide_context=True,
        dag=dag
    )

    stg_load = PythonOperator(
        task_id='stg_load_{}'.format(table_name),
        python_callable=stg_bqimport,
        op_kwargs={'tablename':table_name, 'dag': dag},
        provide_context=True,
        dag=dag
    )    

    merge = PythonOperator(
        task_id='merge_{}'.format(table_name),
        python_callable=prd_merge,
        op_kwargs={'tablename':table_name, 'dag': dag},
        provide_context=True,
        dag=dag
    )
    
    # Tasks for the same table will be chained
    max_ts >> export_gcs >> stg_load >> merge

# DAG is created among the global objects
globals()[dag_id] = dag
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try this method

Comment: Its not picking the 2mins dag. I made these changes. Json syntax error so - https://pastebin.com/ynHtMmmX and `cron_time = '*/10 * * * *'` indent (one tab) and `name 'dag_id' is not defined` so I used `dag_id=(instead of ==)`

Comment: Yes, sorry, I wrote the code in the StackOverflow editor, there could be other problems like this. It was just to give you an idea.